# How do I download a image securely when the user click on a link with PHP?

Tags: php

Want a link that downloads images (*.png, *.jpg, *.gif) to the user's computer.

Tested the following code from the documentation to download a file http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

index.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <a href="download.php?file=nintendo.png">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

download.php

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
} else {
  echo "Ingen fil hittades";
}

?>
```

Have noticed that you can edit the link so you can download everything if you know the file name, even php files.

eg: .../download.php?file=download.php
Will download the file download.php

Is it possible to change so that it is only possible to download images? How do I make a secure download of images when the user clicks on a link?

Comment: don't use real filenames, then. keep a list of available download somewhere (e.g. in a database), and offer up the files by their ID. `download.php?id=42` doesn't tell the user anything about what that file will be, and if you obfuscate the id values (e.g. crypt them somewhow), then it'd be near-impossible to guess other values.

Comment: The most basic way would be to make a list of files that you *allow* to be downloaded.  If they request one not on that list, then don't deliver it.  One way could be to put the files into a certain folder and check to make sure they don't try to escape that folder.  UPDATE: I like @MarcB's solution, try that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the attribute **download**, which is new to HTML5 and is supported by Firefox and Chrome like this but don't know about IE browsers

```
<a id="download" href="img/Chrysanthemum.jpg" download="a.jpg">Download</a>
```

EDIT: to make image simply downloadable, this line is enough.

```
 Content-Disposition: attachment;
```

Comment: Yes why go to all this trouble, simply place the file in a link with target blank and download it,

Comment: I have looked at this but but not very good browser support http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Ok,then The standards-based alternative is to add a Content-Disposition: attachment;

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limiting what each user can download then I would make life difficult for people to stop them guessing file names. You can try hashing the file name so instead of `file=nintendo.png` it would be `file=1be98be84d040d99ca85f5a1786821bf7f4fd37a` and your script could then check in the database to find the right file by searching that hash.

This can stop people guessing file names but it cannot stop people working out what your doing, someone might try different hashes such as SHA-1 and MD5 with any file names they currently know and the system would allow them to download the file. In this case it is a good idea to use a salt, that will make the encryption harder to crack.

To use a salt is very simple, when you generate a hash from your file name, you add another variable into the mix, this could be a special password only you know, the date the file was added to your system. Anything that only you will know.

Here is an example;

Current Link: `file=nintendo.png`

SHA1 Hash: `file=1be98be84d040d99ca85f5a1786821bf7f4fd37a`

SHA1 Hash + "s3cr3tp4ssw0rd" Salt: `file=184649ed65127047f80a46509d0b7447a837b692`

You can see that the salt has changed the hash again. I hope this gives you some sort of idea about obfuscating and hashing urls.

Comment: Is it possible to limit so that users only can download images? My picture names are random number, so it is very difficult for the user to guess a different picture. What I am concerned about is the other files on my server

Comment: Yes you would have to write some functionality into your website to do that. If you have a database with users and file names you could  create a new table that is really simple, one field could be `userid` and the other could be `fileid`. When someone tries to download a file, your site checks the new table to make sure there is an entry that matches both `userid` and `fileid`, if so then let the user download the file, if not then don't let them.

If you dont want to go to that extent then maybe your download page can only allow image files to be downloaded. It can filter by the extension.